# Как проверить, закрыл ли клиент соединение

Tags: php, http, сокет

В PHP через `stream_socket_server` запущен HTTP-сервер. Запросы принимаются через `stream_socket_accept`. В php-apache есть функция `connection_aborted()`. Как через потоковые сокеты проверить, закрыл ли клиент соединение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, это можно проверить через `feof($connection)`